# Scrapy's Selector.extract() Is Broken

Tags: python, command-line, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a simple bot, attempting to scrape a bodybuilding supplement's site and extract supplement information. The bot starts at a page where you select between categories, goes to the page linked to from the first category, and then goes to the first product in that category. Everything works correctly **UNTIL** I get to the `<div>` element containing the actual product information. When I call extract on the div element, it spits out a gibberish version of what it should be spitting out. Here's my spiders code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class IllpumpyouupSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "illpumpyouup"
    allowed_domains = ["illpumpyouup.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://illpumpyouup.com/categories/']

    def parse(self, response):
            print('Starting crawl!')
            hrefs = response.css('.woocommerce').xpath('ul/li/a/@href')

            #loop through hrefs here
            href = hrefs[1]
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_category_page)

    def parse_category_page(self, response):

            hrefs = response.css('.product-inner').xpath('a/@href')

            #loop through hrefs here
            href = hrefs[0]
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_supplement_page)

    def parse_supplement_page(self, response):
            print('Attempting to parse supplement page!')
            facts_div_list = response.css('.supplementfacts')

            print('facts_div_list.extract():\n-----\n{}\n'.format(facts_div_list.extract()))

            facts_div = facts_div_list[0]

            print('facts_div.extract():\n-----\n{}\n'.format(facts_div.extract()))
```

Here's the actual of the element thats being selected in `facts_div`:

```
<div class="supplementfacts">

    <h3>Supplement Facts</h3>

    <p>
        Serving Size: 1-SEDDS Tablet 
        &nbsp;<br>Serving Per Container: 60
        &nbsp;<br>  
        &nbsp;<br>Amount Per Serving
        &nbsp;<br>
        &nbsp;<br>Androst-3,5-Diene-7,17-Dione - 50 mg
        &nbsp;<br>6,7 Dihydroxybergamotin - 100 mg
    </p>

</div>
```

I am trying to get to the text in the p element here. Should be easy, right? Well when I actually run the script with command line command `scrapy crawl illpumpyouup -s LOG_ENABLED=False` this is my exact output, copy and pasted from my terminal (I deleted a bunch of spaces so you could read it easier):

```
Starting crawl!
Attempting to parse supplement page!
facts_div_list.extract():
-----
['<div class="supplementfacts">\r\n\r\n\t <h3>Supplement Facts</h3>\r\n\r\n\t <p>Serving Size: 1-SEDDS Tablet \r\xa0<br>Serving Per Container: 60\r\xa0<br>\r\xa0<br>Amount Per Serving\r\xa0<br>\r\xa0<br>Androst-3,5-Diene-7,17-Dione - 50 mg\r\xa0<br>6,7 Dihydroxybergamotin - 100 mg</p>\r\n\r\n </div>']

facts_div.extract():
-----
<div class="supplementfacts">

                                                <h3>Supplement Facts</h3>

 <br>6,7 Dihydroxybergamotin - 100 mg</p>           <p>Serving Size: 1-SEDDS Tablet 

                                            </div>
```

As you can see, when I call extract on the SelectorList rather than the Selector itself, extract works as it should(I think). I get the correct converted html, in a list of strings. However, when I call extract on the Selector, I am getting a jumbled mess of screwed up HTML, that doesn't even include all of the original data! I have no idea what's going on. Unless I'm mistaken, the Selector.extract() function is being broken by that html somehow. Am I doing something to cause this or is it a broken function? How should I fix this? Thank you for taking the time to read through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the scraped data. It is the way you view it misleading.

You may have noticed that there are a few carriage return characters (`\r`) in the data (e.g. in your `print('facts_div_list.extract():...)` output). Here're examples when a carriage return character is being printed:

```
>>> print 'foo\rbar\rbaz'
baz
>>> print 'is \r my \r data \r missing?'
 missing?
```

In order to view the extracted data, you may try printing something like:

```
facts_div.extract().replace('\r', '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you it was very confusing to me!